# Always-on-top window and keeping focus, on AwesomeWM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I am running a script which creates and closes several windows, hence, I added to my rc.lua a way to keep the window where I am working always on top:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "space",
function(c)
  awful.client.floating.toggle()
  c.ontop = not c.ontop
end),
```

The problem is:when the new window is created, I lose the focus, which passes to the new window.

Is there a way to make that the previous toggle not only keep the window on top, but also with the focus until I toggle it again?

Comment: Just in case: my workaround was to set a rule for that program to open on a specific tag... but I really want a toggle to pin my window on top of everything else, and not to lose focus when other windows appear.

Comment: Does any new window opening switch focus or just the windows from this application/script?

Comment: Any window, but it is not common that I have windows popping up, just with this script.

Comment: Does [this discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=81828) help any?

Comment: Well, not really. I could avoid focus styling altogether, but for me it is in general a feature (if you open a new program, the focus goes to its window), what I am asking for is a way to toggle it, so if I have something creating new windows in a mad way, as this script I mentioned, I can switch off the focus styling temporarily.

Comment: If the general advice works there (and the control is in a function) and you can toggle a global then you should be able to get your desired behavior with that, no?

Comment: You can say: whenever a new window appear, focus or not focus on it. What I want to say is: toggle the behaviour on new windows from now on. And I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Is that option a boolean option or a function whose behavior/code you can control/modify? That was my question.

Comment: It is a rule for new windows. I am not sure how to toggle rules. I will try to investigate that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You don't need to toggle the rule if you can extend its behavior to check for some other global (but toggling the rule might work also)..

Comment: Yes, I can make a rule for that specific script (which is what I have done in fact, read my first comment), but what I want is to have a way to toggle the focus to new windows in general, and toggle it again whenever I want (without editing the rc.lua).

Comment: You are missing my point. If their is a function that controls whether new windows get focus and you can edit that function you can have that function decide whether to give a new window focus based on the state of some global variable and then your "toggle" is changing the state of that global variable.

Comment: There is a function controlling to give focus to a window: you add a rule to "new windows", and you say "give control to it, when it appears". What I do not have is a way to globally say "do not give control to new windows", and this to be toggled when I want. I would need to be able to dynamically  add rules, which is not what you do with, for example, what I put in the main post: the c.ontop is "the current window (c) must be on top". How to say "the new window which has not been created yet, must not get the focus". That I do not know.

Comment: I just added a new question, more specifically on how to modify rules dynamically. If I get a reply to it, I will be able to reply this question too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707357/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-new-rule-to-the-awful-rules-table-dynamically-in-aweso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the `awful.rules.rules` assignment from lines 357-375 of [this awesomerc.lua file](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/awesomerc.lua.in#L357) are in your user's `awesomerc.lua` file and the `awful.client.focus.filter` used in that assignment is the one from [this file](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/lib/awful/client.lua.in#L145) then you should be able to do something like this.

Define a custom focus filter function somewhere in your rc file.

```
function custom_focus_filter(c)
    if global_focus_disable then
        return nil
    end
    return awful.client.focus.filter(c)
end
```

Then use that custom filter function in the rules assignment in place of the original filter function.

```
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- All clients will match this rule.
    { rule = { },
      properties = { ....
                     focus = custom_focus_filter,
                     .... } },
```

And then your toggle function just needs to set and unset the global as appropriate.

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift" }, "f", function ()
    global_focus_disable = not global_focus_disable
end)
```

Comment: Excellent! It worked. Thank you! (and yes, I was totally missing your point, sorry about that)